# MS SQL 2008 R2 - How to Compare or get the Difference from Two Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

First I would like to thank you guys for all of your help with my question(s) and others.

I have MS SQL 2008 R2 and I was getting a sum of two columns like so:

```
SELECT SUM(RATE+RATE_ADDITIONAL) FROM LOADS WHERE INVOICED=1 
and NOT OV_FACTORING=2 and DATE_INVOICED >= '1/1/2007' 
and DATE_INVOICED <= '5/1/2012'
```

but when I try it like this:

```
SELECT SUM(RATE+RATE_ADDITIONAL) FROM LOADS WHERE INVOICED=1 
AND OV_FACTORING=3 OR OV_FACTORING=4 OR OV_FACTORING=5 
and DATE_INVOICED >= '1/1/2007' and DATE_INVOICED <= '5/1/2012'
```

and it comes out to with a different total when it should be the same since in the OV_FACTORING the only values are: 2,3,4, and 5.

I have a column named LOAD_NO and I would like to get that LOAD_NO that is different or non existant in the other query, so something like to compare the two queries and to output the load_no that is different or shows up in one of the queries and not in the other one.

I tried some examples on the site but cannot get them to work.

Again, Thanks for all of your help...

Comment: You are mixing your `OR`s with the `AND`s, put your condition on parenthesis to avoid this.

Comment: Very true Lamak, AND has precedence here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same result, you'll need to isolate the `OV_FACTORING` filters together like so:

```
SELECT SUM(RATE+RATE_ADDITIONAL) 
FROM LOADS WHERE INVOICED=1 AND 
(OV_FACTORING=3 OR OV_FACTORING=4 OR OV_FACTORING=5) AND 
DATE_INVOICED >= '1/1/2007' AND DATE_INVOICED <= '5/1/2012'
```

Comment: ooh, I didn't know about the isolate (), this did the trick, thank you so much for explaining to me why it was happening. so every time I have the same column name and I'm using it more then one time I will have to () isolate it.. got it... thanks again.

Comment: @compcobalt actually any time you are mixing AND and OR you should always use parentheses so that it is clear both to SQL Server and the reader which clauses belong together. I wrote about this 11 years ago: http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-weird-results-when-using-both-and-and-or-in-a-query.html

Comment: @AaronBertrand looks like I have some catching up (reading) to do. Thanks again for everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit in the OV_FACTORING the you can do this:

```
SELECT OV_FACTORING, SUM(RATE+RATE_ADDITIONAL) 
  FROM dbo.LOADS 
  WHERE INVOICED = 1
  AND OV_FACTORING IN (3,4,5)
  AND DATE_INVOICED >= '20070101' 
  AND DATE_INVOICED <= '20120501'
  GROUP BY OV_FACTORING;
```

Or if you really want the `OR` statements. Then you can do this:

```
SELECT OV_FACTORING, SUM(RATE+RATE_ADDITIONAL) 
  FROM dbo.LOADS 
  WHERE INVOICED = 1
  AND (OV_FACTORING=3 OR OV_FACTORING=4 OR OV_FACTORING=5)
  AND DATE_INVOICED >= '20070101' 
  AND DATE_INVOICED <= '20120501'
  GROUP BY OV_FACTORING;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to see that the numbers in the table are accurate, check the results of:

```
SELECT OV_FACTORING, SUM(RATE+RATE_ADDITIONAL) 
  FROM dbo.LOADS 
  WHERE INVOICED = 1
  AND DATE_INVOICED >= '20070101' 
  AND DATE_INVOICED <= '20120501'
  GROUP BY OV_FACTORING;
```

Some general comments that don't relate to the problem:

- carriage returns and indenting make queries 100X more readable
- never use regional formats for dates - is 5/1/2012 May 1 or Jan 5? ([blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries))
- specify the schema prefix for your queries ([blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix))

Comment: No @Siva, my intention was to show the individual OV_FACTORING totals so he can see that the data in the table is accurate, and it's just his OR condition that is making the totals seem wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(RATE+RATE_ADDITIONAL) 
FROM LOADS 
WHERE INVOICED=1 
AND (OV_FACTORING=3 OR OV_FACTORING=4 OR OV_FACTORING=5) 
AND DATE_INVOICED >= '1/1/2007' 
AND DATE_INVOICED <= '5/1/2012
```